# Does using service worker in Polymer app interfer with Firebase Hosting rewrites?

Tags: firebase, polymer, google-cloud-functions, polymer-1.0, firebase-hosting

I try to add some rewrites to my firebase.json to invoke some functions at some paths but the functions are called only once or sometimes at some seemingly random times. My Polymer app uses service worker to pre-cache all the views.

I can only think that caching is somehow the reason that my rewrites are not invoking the Firebase functions all the time? Any solution to this?

Also, does login status have anything to do with this?

Here's my firebase.json:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build/es5-bundled",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "test"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and my test function :

```
const fs = require('fs');
exports.test = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    let indexHTML = fs.readFileSync('./hosting/index.html').toString();
    //I tried to limit cache hoping this might solve the issue, don't see any difference
    res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=10, s-maxage=10');
    res.status(200).send(indexHTML);
})
```

***Edit***

I can confirm that when I use incognito in Chrome my function is called each time as long as I use a new window. So I'm inclined to think the issue is the cache. How to solve it through such that the service worker purpose is not defeated, I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't know the full solution, but maybe this - I found my solution (workbox sw) to add  the routes to be ignored in  `navigateFallbackDenylist: [/^\/backoffice/]` - see https://github.com/vite-pwa/vite-plugin-pwa/issues/218#issuecomment-1122615449 .  Putting this here because I got here using Google search.